# Unexpected behaviour when adding CALayer as sublayer to UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, calayer

I have tableView with custom cells. Each cell has property "name" and "image". What I am trying to do is to add border around image. This part works. But when I try to add backgroundColor to CALayer, than all I can see in tableView is CALayer without UIImage.

Here is code for better understanding and example with setting background color.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var channelImage: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            let borderLayer = CALayer()
            let borderFrame = CGRect(x: -4, y: -4, width: channelImage.frame.size.width+8, height: channelImage.frame.size.width+8)
            borderLayer.frame = borderFrame
            borderLayer.cornerRadius = 4
            borderLayer.borderWidth = 0.5
            borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            channelImage.layer.insertSublayer(borderLayer, at: 0)
            channelImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
            borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            self.channelImage.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.channelImage.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
```

without background color:

```
@IBOutlet weak var channelImage: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        let borderLayer = CALayer()
        let borderFrame = CGRect(x: -4, y: -4, width: channelImage.frame.size.width+8, height: channelImage.frame.size.width+8)
        borderLayer.frame = borderFrame
        borderLayer.cornerRadius = 4
        borderLayer.borderWidth = 0.5
        borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        channelImage.layer.insertSublayer(borderLayer, at: 0)
        channelImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.channelImage.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.channelImage.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Here are also images referenced to first and second example:

[image]

[image]

I did a lot of searching but I didnt found answer for my situation.

Here is complete code of this Cell

```
class ChannelCell: UITableViewCell, ChannelSettable {

    static let reusableID = "channelCell"

    var channel: Channel? = nil {
        didSet {
            self.channelName.text = channel?.channelName ?? ""
            self.channelImage.image = UIImage(named: channel?.channel ?? "") ?? UIImage(named: "TV")
            self.channelCategory.text = channel?.chCategory ?? ""
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var channelName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelCategory: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelImage: UIImageView! {
        didSet {
            let borderLayer = CALayer()
            let borderFrame = CGRect(x: -4, y: -4, width: channelImage.frame.size.width+8, height: channelImage.frame.size.width+8)
            borderLayer.frame = borderFrame
            borderLayer.cornerRadius = 4
            borderLayer.borderWidth = 0.5
            borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            channelImage.layer.insertSublayer(borderLayer, at: 0)
            channelImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.channelName.font = DesignHelper.channelNameFont
        self.channelCategory.font = DesignHelper.channelCategoryFont
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a border directly to the UIImageView's layer like that:

```
channelImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
channelImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
```

you don't have to bother with an extra layer to do that.

However if you still need to add an extra CALayer there try using these methods:

```
func insertSublayer(CALayer, above: CALayer?)
func insertSublayer(CALayer, below: CALayer?)
```

Comment: I know how to add border directly to UIImageView, but in my situation I want border to be in separate layer, since the border frame size needs to be bigger than frame size of an image. I have also tried both two methods that you have mentioned and the result is still the same.

Comment: If you just want to add a bigger border than the ImageView you could do it using UIKit  to insert a subview below imageView that is bigger. Then set its background color. Than you could round its corners with CALayer property if you like. You could use insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:) or insertSubview(_:belowSubview:) from UIView class to do that.

Comment: This could go, but when I would like to change the offset of CALayer frame size comparing to UIImage frame size I would have to change constraints etc and this is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: are you sure you isolated the problem correctly? I cannot reproduce the described bahavior - meaning: I see the image with border around it properly. Look for some external factors then...

Comment: Did you add background color to CALayer? Because withoud background color everything looks OK.

Comment: I have added complete code to my original post if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

sub layer is inserted upon your image view.

if you want to set background of imageView then use

```
channelImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
```

you can add Image inside your layer by using(if you want layer behind the image)

```
borderLayer.contents = channelImage.cgImage
```

Comment: I also know this step / possible solution, but since my CALayer is larger than image frame this does not work for me, because only image layer gets its background color changed. And than you have white border between calayer and image frame. The real question is why is layer inserted above image view even if I am inserting it as a sublayer.

Comment: then just simply add your UIImage inside the CALayer (look at the updated answer)